# Can I boot a machine without using a Hard Disk if its running on a PXE server?

Tags: linux, boot, virtual-machine, pxe

I have an old unuseable computer at home that became useless after a hard disk failure. I don't want to spend money on buying a new PATA IDE HDD for it, so I was wondering if I can use a PXE boot server on my notebook(using a virtual machine with Linux) and boot a Linux on the old machine with PXE without using Hard Disk. It is possible? Do I will need to make some extra configuration or use some specific enviroment do do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, that is possible. In fact, it's even feasible... Provided your notebook supports PXE booting, of course. Though I've never personally tried it. Your laptop would have a decent shot at it being workable if you have a fair bit of RAM in there, as you won't have swap.

There are [some instructions to get PXE booting going here](http://www.howtoforge.com/ubuntu_pxe_install_server). You can also [search further](http://www.google.com/search?channel=fs&q=pxe%20boot%20guide%20linux), of course.

If, by chance, PXE booting is a dead end for you, then I'd setup Linux on a bootable USB drive and run off that... In fact, I'd do that long before PXE, myself.

Comment: +1 for flashdrive. If a computer is new enough to support PXE booting, it probably supports USB booting as well

Comment: The client would also need to support PXE booting. A usb thumb drive or livecd are probably the better solutions.